# Need help to determine whether Mosfet is suitable

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit, dc-dc-converter

I am going to make a regulator circuit with 3.3V 2A output using [MAX1655 Step down controller](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1652-MAX1655.pdf).

I am going to use a solar panel with following specs for input:
Max output voltage: 8.4V

Nominal voltage:6V

Current at MPP: 0.62A

As per the [datasheet for MAX1655(at page 11)](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1652-MAX1655.pdf)  i have to use dual N-Channel Mosfet [IRF7303](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf7303.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355f1be991afa) for the circuit diagram(3.3V /2A Output) at page 10 of the datasheet.

Questions:
1)Can i use two units of [IRFZ44N](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfz44n.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563b3575220b) instead of  [IRF7303](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf7303.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355f1be991afa) in the circuit(3.3V/2 A Output)? ( IRF7303 is unavailable  at local shops near me and the Mosfet they have with closest specs to IRF7303 is IRFZ44N )

2)Would the MAX1655 Controller be damaged by the use of IRFZ44N? Would i face any other problems?

Comment: What is your input voltage ?

Comment: @LongPham I have updated the question

Comment: Compare the power available from  the solar panel (6 * 0.62) with the power output you require (3.3 * 2) before going any further.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yea i know that. But , the load current wont be 2A . It would be around 1A ,but i just wanted the circuit to be capable of delivering 2A Max.

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended.  Look for a FET with a lower gate threshold voltage - the IRFZ44N has a maximum gate threshold voltage of 4 volts (this is the gate voltage when the FET starts to turn on.)  Choose a FET with a similar gate threshold voltage and low on resistance, with similar input capacitance and gate charge.